# Unable to Set environment variable in PHP for unit tests

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm a newbie to PHP. I've just started writing unit tests. I'm unable to set an environment variable in unit tests. Here is my code.

```
$currentPage = Store_Config::get('page');
echo "Page is::".$currentPage;
```

When I run the application in browser, it gives value.

- **Output**
  Page is::Home

  But, for unit tests, I'm not able to get it. It says..

PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in /home/bigc/company/tests/Unit/Lib/GeneralNizamTest.php on line 18

How can I overcome this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is on `/home/bigc/company/tests/Unit/Lib/GeneralNizamTest.php on line 18` Show code from this location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap file to set environment:

**bs.php**

```
<?php 
  define('SOME_VAR', 1);
```

**EnvTest.php**

```
<?php
class OfferTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testEnv() {
    $this->assertEquals(1, SOME_VAR);
  }
}
```

Run with:

```
phpunit --bootstrap bs.php EnvTest.php
```